# Группировка ключей объекта

Tags: json

Задан объект:

```
var  A= {
  "data.photo.ok": "user",
  "data.users.mama": "maman",
  "data.users.son": "bob",
  "hous": "moscow",
  "count": 2
};
```

Зада следующая: преобразовать заданный объект в новый объект, в котором ключи надо разбить на секции символом `.` с группировкой схожих ключей. Например:

```
{
"data": {
    "photo": {
      "ok": "user"
    },
    "users": {
     "mama": "maman",
      "son": "bob"
    }
  },
  "hous": "moscow",
  "count": 2
}
```

Что сделал я:
Взял каждый ключ объекта "А" и сделал из него массив,
потом из каждого элемента массива получаю отдельный объект.

Код:

```
"data": {
    "photo": {
      "ok": "user"
    },
"data":{
    "users": {
      "mama": "maman",
               } 
    }
"data":{
    "users": {
      "son": "bob",
               } 
    }
```

......

Так вот вопросы:
1. Как все эти объекты объединить в один? То есть сделать все отдельные объекты как ключи одного объекта? Я закинул их в массив, но нужен объект, а не массив. Как массив преобразовать в объект? Не пойму.
2. Как группировать ключи объекта?

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки. Код не прошу, прошу подсказать правильный алгоритм решения. Я понимаю, что я делаю это через одно место.
Прошу подсказать в деталях, как сие можно реализовать? Хотя бы куда копать?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Сперва думал продемонстрировать мощь библиотеки Underscore.js на примере данной задачи, но оказалось, что задача решается без применения всяких `_.groupBy` и `_.indexBy`.

> Код не прошу, прошу подсказать правильный алгоритм решения.

Внимание, дальше будет решение. Если хотите решить самостоятельно то подсказка такая: **Рекурсия по кускам пути `"data"`, `"users"`, ....**

Вот Вам решение на чистом JS:

```
// конвертирует в целевой формат
function convert( original ) {
    var result = {};
    for( key in obj ) {
        if( !original .hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            // пропускаем всякие унаследованные ключи
            continue;
        }
        // разбили путь на отдельные куски
        var path = key.split( "." ); // ["data", "photo", "ok"] 

        // рекрсивно вставили отдельные куски пути в объект result
        // вместе с последним куском пути будет вставлено
        // его значение original [key] из оригинального объекта
        recursiveInsert( result, path, original [key] );
    }
    return result;
}

// если в path несколько строк, вставляет в obj пустой объект с ключом path[0]
// если в path только одна строка, то вставляется пара path[0]:final
// final это значение полей в исходном объекте ("maman", "bob", 2 и т.д.)
function recursiveInsert( obj, path, final ) {
    // первый кусок пути
    var current = path[0];

    if( path.length == 1 ) {
        // выход из рекурсии
        obj[current] = final;
        return;
    }
    if( !obj[current] ) {
        // объект мог существовать и быть непустым
        obj[current] = {};
    }
    // отрезаем использованный кусок пути. Он больше нигде не понадобится
    path.splice(0, 1);
    // тут path уже содержит только хвост пути

    // рекрсивно вызываем вставку для только что созданного объекта и хвоста пути
    recursiveInsert( obj[current], path, final );
}
```

Единственное ограничение задаёт сама постановка задачи. Что, если у Вас могут быть такие пути:

```
var problemExample = {
    "data.photo.ok": "ok",
    "data.photo": "photo"
};
```

тогда значение из `data.photo` перетрёт объект `{"ok": "ok"}`:

```
result = { "data": { "photo": "photo" } }
```